# Extruding imported svg does only translate curve

Tags: import, extrude, svg

I created a svg in inkscape.

[image: inkscape svg]

and imported it in blender.

[image: imported in blender]

Edit mode, with the display of handles turned off looks like

[image: edit mode]

Selecting the curve by selecting one vertex and and pressing ctrl-L and pressing E to extrude it, restricting it by pressing Z does only result in translation.

I expected the mesh to become like a strip/band/wall.

[image: after trying to extrude]

The extrude curve menu that comes up shows some alternatives

[image: The extrude curve menu]

...but changing to something else than translation here does not result in anything.

Why not?

Comment: Blender does not support this on curves (as far as I know). You can extrude curves only if created from 'add/surface/' and choose a curve (not from 'add/curve')

Comment: That is not how you extrude curves in Blender, use the *Extrude* property in the *Properties Window > Object Data > Geometry > Extrude*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the object mode, press ALT+C and transform the curve into the mesh. Go to the edit mode and then extrude it along z-axis.